# In Selenium Webdriver, can we initialize a webdriver object with the HTML source instead of a URL

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

In one of my test case I hit the rest API using restAssured and the API always returns the response in pure HTML. The returned HTML is basically the source of a valid page. Now I can't use `webDriver.get(URL);` method since I don't have a direct URL.

Does selenium provide any such method in which I can open the HTML source directly in the browser instead of providing a URL?

Comment: I am not able to understand the why would you need webdriver methods in rest assured. Your problem statement is not very clear. Can you rephrase it.

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea is to just open a blank page and then *set the inner HTML of the current page*:

```
String innerHtml = "your HTML here";
driver.executeScript("document.innerHTML = " + innerHtml);
```

Or, you can also save that HTML into a file and then [open the file via `file://` protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17972885/771848):

```
driver.get("file://path/to/file.html")
```